# How do I keep the trailing zero (or zeros) when I round with Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

The title says it all. Consider the following example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RoundToDecimalsDefinedByEndUser()
    Dim DecimNum As Integer
    DecimNum = InputBox("How many decimals do you want?", "Enter")
    Cells(1, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(Cells(1, 1).Value, DecimNum)
End Sub
```

Consider a situation where the end user wants to have 2 decimals, and the number to be rounded is 0.10111.
The result should be 0.10, but Excel forces the result to be 0.1. Any suggestions on how to keep the trailing zero(s)?

Comment: what is displayed by excel in a cell will be dependent on the formatting of the cells

Comment: If you want to keep trailing zero then it will converted to string not as value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RoundToDecimalsDefinedByEndUser()
    Dim DecimNum As Double, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    DecimNum = InputBox("How many decimals do you want?", "Enter")
    With Cells(1, 1)
      .Value = wf.Round(.Value, DecimNum)
      .NumberFormat = "0." & wf.Rept("0", DecimNum)
    End With
End Sub
```

This will leave **A1** as a numeric value.

Comment: `Rept`..very nice function: makes things a lot more concise.

Comment: @whytheq  my first thought was to use a *loop*

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thank you for your suggestion - it works perfectly. Several important lessons arise from your solution. One of them is how a couple of things are executed handily to the cell in question using With...End With Statement. Another one is of course the inventive use of the Rept function. Btw, I was surprised to find out that this topic had not been exhaustively discussed earlier in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jaggedjava *REPT()* is useful in string processing.

Answer (score 3):

Below the line of code `cells(1,1).value...` you could add some more code based on:

`cells(1,1).numberformat...`

The number format you use would be `#,0.0000000` - somehow you need to adjust the number of zeros to equal `DecimNum`

```
dim x as integer
dim numForm as string: numForm = "#,0."
for x = 0 to decimNum
   numForm = numForm & "0"
next x
```

(not tested as I do not have Excel on this machine)